# Parse Issue: Expected Statement only when archiving

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parsing, archive, expected-exception

I get a `Parse Issue` `Expected Statement` error only when trying to `archive` my XCode project. I do not receive this error and the app runs fine when I regularly build it instead of archiving.

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

    if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SavedUsername] length] && [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SavedPassword] length]) {
        [self.btnRememberMe setSelected:YES];
        self.isButtonSelected = YES;
        self.txtFieldUsername.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SavedUsername];
        self.txtFieldPassword.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SavedPassword];

//        NSLog(@"username = %@ , pass = %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SavedUsername], [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:SavedPassword]);
        if ([self isAllFieldVerified])
            #ifdef DEBUG
                NSLog(@"all fields are verified");
            #endif
            //[self makeWebAPICallMethodCalling];
    }else {
        [self.btnRememberMe setSelected:NO];
        self.isButtonSelected = YES;
        self.txtFieldUsername.text = @"";
        self.txtFieldPassword.text = @"";
    }


}
```

The parser error is thrown by the `else` line...

Comment: enclose the nested if statement, i.e. if ([self isAllFieldVerified]), with brackets and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `#ifdef` for the `NSLog` statement. When you do a non-debug build the `NSLog` line isn't there leaving an `if` statement with no code.

Try this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    if ([self isAllFieldVerified])
        NSLog(@"all fields are verified");
#endif
```

or at least add curly braces:

```
    if ([self isAllFieldVerified]) {
        #ifdef DEBUG
            NSLog(@"all fields are verified");
        #endif
    }
```

This is an example of why it's always a good idea to use curly braces, even if there is only one line.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Why would this still compile and run on my iphone if it doesn't work on the archiver?

Comment: As I stated at the start of my answer, the code is valid for a debug build but not a non-debug build. That's the whole point of the `#ifdef DEBUG` line. When you were testing on your iPhone you were doing a debug build but when you archive you do a distribution (non-debug) build.